# Use mmap() in application receiving piped data?

Tags: c++, c, linux, pipe, mmap

Is it possible to use mmap() in a C++ application on Linux which must receive piped input from a file and if so, is this faster than reading individual/page_amount bytes from the stream?

I'm not sure mmap() is possible because piping involves a stream whereas wouldnt mmap() require all of the data availale immediately?

Answer (score 3):

You can not `mmap` a stream because data in a stream buffer is intended to be read only once. Also the length of receivable data is indeterminable at runtime. Your best bet is to `mmap` a sufficient amount of memory and then use it as a receiving buffer.

If you are using `stdio` functions to read data form your stream then the chunk size won't matter. The library will automatically choose the most optimal one (often one page at a time). But if you intend to use `read` then reading in chunks of pages will give you the best performance.

Comment: So read() on page_size bytes is the fastest way to read piped input? Faster than reading page_size bytes in to mmap() and then iterating on it? I only need to see each byte once.

Comment: @mezamorphic These will be both equally as fast, but probably even faster and more portable way will be to `fread` (`stdio.h`) into any arbitrary buffer with a chunk size that is most optimal for your application.